# Android listView as the listView from iPhone

Tags: android, iphone, android-listview

I would like to implement an ListView similar to one form the iPhone.
[image: Here is the image]

The first element of the table is an image and the others are text plus arrow.

I know how to use an custom image adapter but only for an unique customization, not to customize each row.

That information is static, I should only have the possibility to click the desired element.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi, strange, I can see it on stack.

Comment: Quoting the Android design guidelines: http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/pure-android.html "A common pattern on other platforms is the display of right-pointing carets on line items that allow the user to drill deeper into additional content. Android does not use such indicators on drill-down line items. Avoid them to stay consistent with the platform and in order to not have the user guess as to what the meaning of those carets may be."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found the solution,

I can use a header for the list view and a customized borders.
Here is an example:

listview_border.xml in drawable folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<stroke android:width="4dp" android:color="#FFFFFFFF" />
<padding android:left="7dp" android:top="7dp"
        android:right="7dp" android:bottom="7dp" />
<corners android:radius="15dp" />
<solid android:color="#FFFFFFFF"/>
</shape>
```

for the listview, set:

```
 android:background="@drawable/listview_border"
```

Then for the hedser, create a listviaw_header.xml in layouts:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

   <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/imageView1"
       android:layout_width="128dp"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:src="@drawable/contact_image_fr"
       android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Then set the header:

```
ListView contact = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.contactListView);


    View header = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.contact_listview_header, null);

    contact.addHeaderView(header);
```

And that's all. Enjoy...